# Angular2 Height Animation - same state transition

Tags: css, angular, animation

I have the following animation code attached to my component

```
animations:[
        trigger('slide', [
            state('show', style({
                height: '*'
            })),
            state('hide', style({
                position: 'relative',
                height: 0,
                overflow: 'hidden'
            })),
            transition('show <=> hide',animate('130ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
```

This is quite hard to explain, (and I can't seem to get animations to work on plunker) but here goes.

The current functionality is as follows:

1. User clicks a button to display table.
2. Table smoothly slides into view from below a div.
3. User click button again.
4. Table smoothly slides out of the view up into the div.

The desired functionality is as follows:

1. User clicks a button to display table.
2. Table smoothly slides into view from below a div.
3. More rows are added to table (could be a large number of rows)
4. **Animation handles the new table height and instead of just instantly being displayed there is a smoothing animation to gradually move to the new height.**
5. User Clicks button.
6. Table slides back up under div again.

   Edit: here is a [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/7qWuHmbFFie4p8Y9h53T/) demo. You can see when you add/remove rows from the table the animation does not smoothly move to the new height.

The problem is caused because if you are in **true** state and rows are added.

The animation will not transition to **true** again, because it is already in **true** state.

So how will I trigger a transition to the "newHeight" state when items are added?

Comment: The problem is related to the height being calculated only when the element is created. I don't think it's possible to force the animation API to compute it again.

Comment: maybe this solution is helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47492134/5155810

Comment: @MartinCremer you solution's suggest is unrelated

Comment: @canerandagio i think it fits perfectly. You can wrap anything with a changing height with it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick, rough, animation example using angular animations API:

https://embed.plnkr.co/7qWuHmbFFie4p8Y9h53T/

I would play around with that plnkr until you get the animations right. You can hide the element behind something by either removing the table entirely after animating it down by toggling the animation with an *ngIf in your template, or do it the way I show in the plnkr, but toggle the visibility of the table after the animation is complete. [I prefer the *ngIf way.](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3139-experimenting-with-conditional-enter-leave-animations-in-angular-2-rc-6.htm)

**For individual rows being added or removed**:

I would add an @animation to every row of the table and enable the up animation if the number of rows increases, or down if it decreases.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood, I already have my animation working to a degree. The problem comes from the fact that when you already in "true" state, you will not get another transition to "true" when rows are added.

Comment: Okay I get it. Read a little to quickly. In that case, I would add an @animation to every row of the table and enable the up animation if the number of rows increases, or down if it decreases.

Comment: I will try again after the weekend and let you know. Thanks for your help!