# Angular Animation For Dynamically Changing Height

Tags: angular, animation

I've successfully gotten a panel to animate expanding and closing when entering and leaving the DOM. The problem is I now have a busy indicator inside the panel prior to showing details, and the animation only occurs for opening the busy indicator, and snaps when the detail content is shown.

How can I get the Angular animation to animate on any height change?

I have an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-animation-for-dynamically-changing-height?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
trigger('expandCollapseDetails', [
    state('void', style({
        'height': '0px',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    })),
    //element being added into DOM.
    transition(':enter', [
        animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({
            'height': '*',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        }))
    ]),
    //element being removed from DOM.
    transition(':leave', [
        animate('500ms ease-in-out', style({
            'height': '0px',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        }))
    ])
])
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I've written a component that smoothly animates the height of projected content if that content changes.
It's used like this:

```
<smooth-height [trigger]="content">
  {{content}}
</smooth-height>
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-kugxw7

This is the component:

```
import {ElementRef, HostBinding, Component, Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {animate, style, transition, trigger} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: 'smooth-height',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host {
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  `],
  animations: [
    trigger('grow', [
      transition('void <=> *', []),
      transition('* <=> *', [
        style({height: '{{startHeight}}px', opacity: 0}),
        animate('.5s ease'),
      ], {params: {startHeight: 0}})
    ])
  ]
})
export class SmoothHeightComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input()
  trigger: any;

  startHeight: number;

  @HostBinding('@grow') grow: any;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}  
              
  ngOnChanges(){
    this.startHeight = this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight;

    this.grow = {
      value: this.trigger,
      params: {startHeight: this.startHeight}
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example is a bit different than mine (my dynamic content isn't just a string), but I think I adapted yours enough to get by. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. Regarding to your plnkr, i think you could use it like <smooth-height [indicator]="areDetailsVisible">...

Comment: Nice idea. `indicator` is actually the trigger for the animation.

Comment: Thanks, changed 'indicator' to 'trigger', it's a better word indeed!

Comment: Because calling functions (including `get` getters) in the template may be considered bad practice, I would suggest changing `@HostBinding('@grow')` to a simple property: `@HostBinding('@grow') grow: any;`. Then, inside `ngOnChanges`, set that property. `this.grow = { value: this.trigger, params: { startHeight: this.startHeight } };`. This prevents `get grow()` from being called many times as Angular Change Detection determines if the value is consistent. Otherwise, I love this answer and it works perfectly for me!

Comment: @NickAlexander thanks a lot, i appreciate your idea, i've changed the code accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisMoore what did you do to adapt it for content other than a string? It's working for me when expanding, but not when collapsing

Answer (score 18):

I made a directive based on @MartinCremer answer. I think using a directive makes more sense since by doing that, you also should add the animation to your parent component (and it's close the standard way of adding animations).

So inside my `animations.ts` file. I've added the animation:

```js
    export const smoothHeight = trigger('grow', [
      transition('void <=> *', []),
      transition('* <=> *', [style({ height: '{{startHeight}}px', opacity: 0 }), animate('.5s ease')], {
        params: { startHeight: 0 }
      })
    ]);
```

then you should add this animation to your parent component (the component that you want to use the animation inside it):

```js
    import { smoothHeight } from '@app/animations';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-parent',
      templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
      animations: [smoothHeight]
    })
```

And here is the directive which is really close to the component of @MartinCremer:

```js
    import { Directive, OnChanges, Input, HostBinding, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[smoothHeight]',
      host: { '[style.display]': '"block"', '[style.overflow]': '"hidden"' }
    })
    export class SmoothHeightAnimDirective implements OnChanges {
      @Input()
      smoothHeight;
      pulse: boolean;
      startHeight: number;

      constructor(private element: ElementRef) {}

      @HostBinding('@grow')
      get grow() {
        return { value: this.pulse, params: { startHeight: this.startHeight } };
      }

      setStartHeight() {
        this.startHeight = this.element.nativeElement.clientHeight;
      }

      ngOnChanges(changes) {
        this.setStartHeight();
        this.pulse = !this.pulse;
      }
    }
```

Finally inside `parent.component.html` use the directive:

```html
    <div [smoothHeight]="yourAnimationIndicator">
      // any html content goes here
    </div>
```

Just replace `yourAnimationIndicator` with the variable that the animation should trigger on change of its value.

Here is a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6gagz?file=src/app/components/parent/parent.component.css)

Comment: This is a fantastic solution, thanks!

Comment: It will even better if you can integrate a stackblitz example. :)

Comment: I've edited to add the stackblitz demo (I'll leave it here in case it gets rejected: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6gagz?file=src/app/components/parent/parent.component.css )

Comment: For some reason, the stackblitz no longer seems to work. Cannot use import statement outside a module

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something similar with a bit of css and js:

## Solution:

#### component.ts

```
import { Component, OnChanges, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-exandable',
  templateUrl: './exandable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./exandable.component.css']
})
export class ExandableComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input()
  src;

  @ViewChild('expandable')
  expandable;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.updateHeight();
  }

  updateHeight(delay = 0) {
    const el = this.expandable.nativeElement;

    setTimeout(() => {

      const prevHeight = el.style.height;
      el.style.height = 'auto';
      const newHeight = el.scrollHeight + 'px';
      el.style.height = prevHeight;

      setTimeout(() => {
        el.style.height = newHeight;
      }, 50);
    }, delay);
  }
}
```

#### css

```
.expandable {
  transition: height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

### Code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-il71da

Comment: I appreciate that you answered this sans `animations` dependency. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had some jump issues with @Martin Cremer's solution. With complex content that needs a little time to display, the target height set when the animation is triggered wasn't the actual final height of the new content.

So I used 2 containers, the inner one #content, used to listen to the height changes, and the outer one #container, of which I adjust the height to match the inner one (with a smooth transition).

I copy the the height changes from the inner to the outer container as long as the animation is on going, after being triggered, hence the msSpeed variable property.

On initialization, I don't do it, hence the initDone property.

The HTML:

```
<div #container
     class="container"
     [style.transition]="animationOn?('height ease '+msSpeed+'ms'): 'none'">
    <div #content
         class="content">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE TS:

```js
import { animate, style, transition, trigger } from '@angular/animations';
import { Component, ElementRef, HostBinding, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Renderer2, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-smooth-height',
  templateUrl: './smooth-height.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./smooth-height.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('grow', [
      transition('void <=> *', []),
      transition('* <=> *', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate('{{speed}} ease')])
    ])
  ]
})
export class SmoothHeightComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() trigger: any;
  @Input() msSpeed: number = 500;

  @ViewChild('container') container: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('content') content: ElementRef;

  initDone = false;
  animationOn = false;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  @HostBinding('@grow') get grow(): any {
    return { value: this.trigger, params: { speed: this.msSpeed + 'ms' } }; 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const observer = new ResizeObserver((entries: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
      const contentHeight = entries[0].contentRect.height;
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.container.nativeElement, "height", (contentHeight) + 'px');
    })
    observer.observe(this.content.nativeElement)

    this.initDone = true;
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    if (this.initDone) {
      this.animationOn = true;
      setTimeout(() => { this.animationOn = false; }, this.msSpeed)
    }
  }
}
```

THE CSS:

```
:host {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: visible;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.content {
  height: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Transitions and unfixed sizes (fit-content, max-content, etc..) do not communicate well.

Here's a sample of **hack** for this case:

```
animations: [
    trigger('openCloseAnimation', [
      state('open', style({ maxHeight: '100px', overflow: 'auto' })),
      state('closed', style({ maxHeight: '60px' })),
      transition('* => closed', animate('0.2s')),
      transition('* => open', animate('0.5s')),
    ]),
  ],
```

With MaxHeight, your div/container dont will exceed more than 'max-content', but will behave with 'fit-content'.